# Php how to replace string range dynamically with preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace range of characters dynamically using preg_replace. e.g. D01 to D99 i want to replace this string range with blank and M01 to M99 want to replace it with `<br/>` tag. I am trying to replace it using array of static values. This is my code.

```
$str1 = "This is mystrD01 and this is D03just for testingD02.M01Loream ipsum text1M02loream ipsum text2";
$arr1 = array("D01","D02","D03","D04","M01","M02","M03");
$replaceArr = array("","","","","<br/>","<br/>","<br/>");
echo str_replace($str_arr1,$replace_arr2,$str2);
```

Comment: There is also `preg_replace_callback()` or you can just use [arrays in `preg_replace()` like in this demo](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj7AI4CLS6W4pEjBVkHJxcBQx8XSUscXSPtaWipZw6UKilLT44tSC3ISk1M1otX1XWJSYlL01XXU9X0hrFidaCUlHQV1m6QifTsgTwGkURNoQGpyRj6YA2T//w8A) (not sure, if this is what you're after).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace` on the array with a regex match.

`D\d*` Will match "D" and then any number of digits after.

```
$arr1 = array("D01","D02","D03","D04","M01","M02","M03");
$arr1 = preg_replace("/D\d*/", '', $arr1);
$arr1 = preg_replace("/M\d*/", '<br />', $arr1);
```

Output -

```
["","","","","<br/>","<br/>","<br/>"]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) available, which is usually the best means for doing any dynamic replacements. Use it with a pattern like [`([DM])\d\d(?!\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/a6nT0o/3) and replace depending on the [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

```
$new_str = preg_replace_callback('/([DM])\d\d(?!\d)/', function($m) {
  return $m[1]=="D" ? "" : '<br/>';
}, $str1);
```

[See this PHP demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##XY/BaoQwAETvfsU0CCosNbG3utaLhx4q7KG3dZFszK62JoYk0pbSb7ehtJfCnN7APMaMZtv29eHxEEWx85ahAnkeJ4cQ9RFIQxm4HuB/YUPvXlbncVksvHR@0teGFrctZU@LlVxhMm5VoXr3rKXF/B8WpAwqLd/6MB5sxsprb6WZuZC94PN85uI1TfL02LSnrBu6Ia1vuiHLkx0uqxZ@WnQaqwyfEWClX61GrI7sVFWkIahBCO6R7M82f0jK6GuHn19ZsEoxLvhTl9G2fQM)  (The [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is used to not match eg `D001`)

The advantage of using a callback is, that you have a wide scope in dealing with captured values. Regex alone is not good for matching numeric ranges but could easily be further checked by any function.

---

Anyway your sample task can be done by [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with arrays as well.

```
$new_str = preg_replace(['/D\d\d(?!\d)/', '/M\d\d(?!\d)/'], ["", '<br/>'], $str1);
```

[Another PHP demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##XY7PC4IwGIbv/hVfI1BB2mZHLS8eOiR46KYR5pYa/hjbpPrr14qCCN7L93zwvK9ohTFxku9yx1kqLSlsAB3aToHN8LAkJRSqkYH@wJSsr7PScJkkaK50NzYpCVcZoftJ8mqATqh5sK@7phkJ@38YoshWjfx2snLbJiRvTpKLvqq5V7g4LVnJvGRRMh@7Abg4@wXHAAqELI7PEm9f53u1b528bif4iiPHmCc)

Comment: A single call is better than 2, +1